# What is the best way to calculate rank of users in Django

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have a web-site written in django. Site have users who have points and a rank according to their points.

```
class Profile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    points = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
```

When a user gains a point his/her rank will be changed and so other users as well.
The question is what is the best way to calculate rank of the users and when i should calculate or how often?

Thanks.

Comment: this link may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518913/designing-a-database-for-a-user-points-system-in-django

Comment: and also a good Django ranking algorithm here http://www.lonelycode.com/2008/07/13/django-ranking-algorithm-reddit-style/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best approach to update the rank of every user each time a single user's  points increase. If you have a lot of users this would be harsh on the back end.

If you want to display the users rank on say a profile page perhaps you could have a query that gets a list of all users ordered by points, store this separately as a dictionary or whatever and cache it heavily. This will is better for performance.

so lets say your users list looks like so(the 1111 etc being the usersid):

`USERS = {
        1111: {'username': 'iskorum',
                 'points':99999
        },
        2222: {'username': 'sidarcy',
                'points':9444
        },
        3333: {'username': 'joeblogs',
                'points':37
        }
    }`

When it comes to actually getting the users rank you can simply find the users position in this stored dictionary.

lets say the users id is 1111

userrank = [i+1 for i,x in enumerate(sorted(USERS)) if x == 1111]

returns 1

No extra DB query's needed

If its only a small site no harm getting the user list each time and finding the current users position in that list.

However if your expecting thousands of users the above may be a better approach.

Edit: You should also cache the sorted list, as discussed in the comments below
sorting the list each time could eat up a lot of memory

Comment: Looks fine but when we will cache this dictionary (i understand from "caching" just a variable, no use of DB? is that wrong?) and caching needs to run over all users, is that easy?

Comment: what id recommend is have a separate model for stuff like this, the dictionary could live in a single field called 'ranks'.

You can use cache.get, cache.set  to remember the returned object
from the DB

from django.core.cache import cache

cachedRanks = cache.get("user_list_by_points")
if cachedRanks :
        return cachedRanks
else:
    cachedRanks = GET FROM MODEL
    cache.get("user_list_by_points", cachedRanks, 10*60)
    return cachedRanks

Comment: Is `user_list_by_points` dictionary or queryset. if it is dictionary how will i create it? I mean creating dictionary isn't laborious.
if it is queryset what is the advantage. Sorry i don't know much about caching.

Comment: i get it :) thanks :)
But now i couldn't get the sorting part. Every time sorting the dictionary is easy when there are ten thousands of users?

Comment: Python should be able to handle it, the only worry would be memory but again caching is your friend here too, you should cache the sorted list in the db. Perhaps even cache the users rank also for a short period of time. 

You could also look into alternative sorting methods in Python and see which is the best for large list objects.