# User Point System DB Design Approach

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am looking point system DB Design. My Question is quite similar to the question that I have found here. : - [Database design - Approach for storing points for users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312372/database-design-approach-for-storing-points-for-users) .

In this system, user earns points when any of this action happens:-

1. User Register on the website. (i.e Active Entry to the User table)
2. User Writes Answer of the Other Users Question. (i.e Entry to the
   Answer table)
3. User Answers are rated be other Users. (i.e Entry to Answer Rating
   Table for the User )
4. User Invites Other Users to Join the platform

From the DB Design Side, I have created these two tables:-

- Action_Master table, and
- User_Action_Point table.

The Action_Master table contains this :-  (id, action_name, action_point)

The User_Action_Point table stores the history of each actions, so it look like this:- 
(id, action_master_id, action_done, created_by, created_at, updated_by, updated_at, deleted_at)

Now the problem here is the User_Action_Point table, it contains the repeated data of the User Table, Answer Table and Answer_rating Table.

This problem is very well addressed by Jeffrey in the first answer of the linked question. According to his answer we should have to execute Views or Stored Procedure to sum up the points from different tables every time. This approach is awesome because we need not to handle the overhead of data deletion or any other changes that may affect the User Points.

But, is that a good way when we need users points very frequently ? Don't you think this approach can increase the db response time or the loads on the MySQL server ?

or I need to store the aggregated Users points data in some table with the overhead of handling repeated data (i.e if anything get deleted then we also have to minus those points in the point table.)

Please Suggest.